# Should I prune "From Scratch" or should I prune "From going forward", using the GUI version 0.17.1.9, and why?

Tags: nodes

I've tried and tried to run my full node about 15 different times over 3 weeks now. It just goes too slow and never syncs. I can never find the answers I need to figure out my personal situation with why I can't get a full local node to work quicker. I did get it to sync like 1 time! I was so happy. That only lasted for about 10 minutes before it just crashed and started the entire syncing process over, why I don't know. I use win10, envy laptop 3 years old, have plenty of storage space and I could utilize an empty new 1tb external hard drive if I needed to but yet for some reason I cant get the full local node to work. I'm giving up, regretfully, and am now going to try the pruned node before I eventually probably end going remote node for rest of my life! haha.Sorry for my ignorance, its certainly not from a lack of effort, persistence, dedication and devotion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pruning is best done on the fly, as pruning an already synced blockchain is a very slow process - a lot slower than setting it to prune from the get go.

About the sync speed, using a spinning hard drive is a major source of slowdown. Monero just doesn't like slow hard drives, so if you have a SSD, it'd sync in hours rather than days. Once synced, the chain can be moved to a HDD where it'll keep up with the network.

As for the chain corrupting on an OS crash, it looks like a bug either in Monero or the OS/filesystem layer. Probably Monero, since there's been a number of such reports, but no known cause yet (and thus no fix).